# Distance between haversine values?

Tags: haversine

I have 2 datasets (say A and B), each with their own latitude and longitude values. I've worked out the Haversine values for each dataset, say hav(A) and hav(b). Now I need to work out the distance between hav(A) and hav(B) in km. I've read through the wiki etc. but I'm still a bit unsure how to do it, my understanding of the mathematics is probably lacking so I apologise if this is a simple question but I'd appreciate some assistance.

I got the difference between hav(A) and hav(B), expecting to get the distance of the two points in km but upon looking over it again, this is almost certainly an incorrect approach.

Comment: Wasn't this posted recently?

Comment: If it was I apologise, I looked through the related questions but didn't see it.